# Expand Markdown formatting toolbar on official iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, ios-app

The toolbar currently used on Stack Exchange's official app for iOS does not have enough formatting options. Also, it does not appear in the comments. These things need to be added to it:

- underline
- strikethrough
- comment support

And finally, of course, comment toolbars would only have comment formatting in it.

Comment: Neither strikethrough nor underline are available in [the Markdown used on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting); why would this be added  to the iOS app?

Comment: @JoshCaswell strikeout **is** supported in chat markdown ...

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible (it would be great if it's implemented though), but the desktop version doesn't have markdown toolbar on comment either...

Comment: @DavidPostill but the app doesn't support chat.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay...but it's not anywhere else, and chat doesn't have a formatting toolbar. So this still doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markdown toolbar in the app is designed to function similarly to the website (both for design simplicity and consistency) and I don't plan to implement any additional features.

There's no markdown toolbar for comments because there's generally not a lot of vertical space for it and because it would only have four buttons.  Instead, formatting is available through the iOS long press menu:

1. [image: Screenshot showing menu with Format option circled.]
2. [image: Screenshot showing formatting menu options: Bold, Italic, Link, Code]